# Why am I not getting an output with torch.save?

Tags: python, pytorch, save

I'm trying to save my trained model with torch.save:

```
torch.save(model, r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\HDF_Group\HDFView\3.1.1\VAE2.hdf5')
```

but still not getting the output in my file .h5 (always empty)
Does someone know why?

Comment: The path passed to `torch.save(` has the suffix `.hdf5`, but in your question you mention a file ending in `.h5`. Are you sure that you're looking at the correct file? If the output file is `.h5`, you may want to edit your question to show the correspondence.

Comment: It's the same ! .h5 or .hdf5

Comment: Does the folder exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists ! created with HDFViewer. It's an .H5 file @hkchengrex

Comment: i'm running into this issue as well when the path points to an s3 location, how did you solve this issue?